# iOS App Force Update - Issues with App Store Update Button Refreshed

Tags: ios, app-store

Once in a while we want to force update our up. We do this by checking with our server at boot and if the new required version of the app is higher then the current installed version we display a typical "Download new Version" button that takes you to the App Store page directly. Here is where we run into issues.

It appears that the "Update/Open" button of the App Store App doesn't refresh immediately, even after the app has propagated properly. It almost seems that once you open the App Store App it needs some time to check the status of all the apps, you can actually force this by clicking on the Update tab, after that the page linked for our app, shows the "Update" button instead of the "Open" button.

Now here is where our users have problems. They open our app and it tells them to update, they click the button and it takes them to the app store which tells them to Open. If they click it, it goes back to the app and they are now in a cycle. 
That seems to happen, if they have good connection, only once, but if not they need to do this cycle at least a couple of times before the App Store App has realized that the button needs to be switched to Update.

Has anyone had to deal with this issue? How have you handled it?

- Wait more time after propagation?
- Special link that forces refresh?
- There is a view to update the app that I think can be called from inside our app without going to the app store?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps add an instruction to your dialog to tell the user to open the "updates" tab?

Comment: You should probably wait some time after a new release to make that version the required version.

Comment: Having the same problem. Please suggest any solution found out for this. Many tricks are available only to force refresh the app store contents by user. But this cannot be teach to all customers who using our application.